# Put .hg or .hg/store out of the project folder for Mercurial

Tags: mercurial

Is it possible to store .hg folder or .hg/store folder out of the project folder? For example my project is in /var/www/project and I want to put .hg (or .hg/store) folder to /mnt/myproject. As a result /var/www/project will not have .hg (or .hg/store) folder in it and /mnt/myproject will be the main repository folder.

The main reason for this that I have not very big diskspace in /var/www/project and want to put repository in mounted folder (on another server) - /mnt/myproject.

Comment: Couldn't you use a symbolic link, in `/var/www/project` to link to your directory `/mnt/myproject`? I wouldn't move around Mercurial's metadata.

Comment: Solution is good, but /var/www/project is web project and moving it to mounted folder (to another server) will cause speed problems.

Comment: Same problem (only worse) putting the metadata on another server.

Comment: But this problem will appear only during commiting, right? Our commits are not huge (project development is not very active), so I don't think that this will cause a big problem. But website is live and should be accessible always.

Comment: I'm sure you know best. This sounds like an exceedingly bad idea to me, but take a full backup and let us know how it works out.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with the [Share Extension](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/ShareExtension) -- create the repo on a volume with space and then create a share of it where you'd like.

Really though, disk is approximately free now, you shouldn't have to resort to trickery like this.